# Write array to cells horizontally

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dynamic list of names on one sheet. On another sheet, I dedicated one column each for each name as the header. I've been adding and delete these columns manually as the list of names changes, but I'm wondering if there's a way to script it but taking the names into an array and displaying them horizontally instead of vertically. so if I have 5 names, it'll display the names as in the first row across 5 columns.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the transpose? i am sure it will work.

Comment: Well that was simple. I didn't even know that was a function. Thanks!

Comment: I do have a follow up question. I have a script that will delete all unused columns. However, since I do not know how long my list will be i just use Transpose(D2:D) which will cover any amount of values. However, if I do that, then my script will not delete the unused rows. Is there a way for transpose to dynamically grab only up to the last row?

Comment: No may be there is no way to delete the rest of data after doing transpose we just manually delete them. other wise you should create the custom code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with inbuilt function of excel or csv sheet
just copy your vertically cells and paste it where you show it as horizontally,
then just select first cell of copied column and click on paste special then select transpose option and the column is converted into the row means it will be horizontal.